# Jquery disable form if bad form

Tags: jquery, forms

**My Script**

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){


    var nombre_in=jQuery("#name_id").val();
    var email_in=jQuery("#email_id").val();

    var condition = true; 


    if (nombre_in=="" || email_in=="")
    {


    jQuery('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    jQuery('form').bind('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();}); 



    }


    });

    </script>


 <form name="surveyForm" id="forma_survey" method="post" action="client.php">

<a href="javascript:document.surveyForm.submit();">Send Form</a>
</form>
```

I try disable send form if i get empty fields from form , but no get disable send form , it´s possible do with jquery , i can´t get works

Thank´s !

Comment: Have you looked in the console to see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do it in a more automated way, but just as an example, to disable form submission, you can subscribe to the form `submit` event and trigger `event.preventDefault()` if it's in a state in wich you want to cancel the submission.

```
$( "#forma_survey" ).submit(function( event ) {

    var nombre_in=jQuery("#name_id").val();
    var email_in=jQuery("#email_id").val();

    if(!nomber_in || !email_in)
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

To understand more about the `submit` event, please refer to: http://api.jquery.com/submit/